# Issues looping through JSON data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My JSON data:

```
var menu = {"parent":[
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Information",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": 1000,
      "name": "Example"
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Something"
},  
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Something else",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": 2000,
      "name": "Yay"
    }
  ]
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://sable-belief-1704.justapis.io/parentmenu", false);
xhr.send();

var responseJson = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
var responseParent = responseJson.parent;

for(var i in responseParent) {

    if (responseParent[i].hasOwnProperty('child'))
    {
        console.log(responseParent[i]);
        console.log(responseParent[i].child[i]);
    }
}
});
```

I'm stumped here. This code works fine for the first object that has a child object. But when it loops to the second object that has a child object, it will run the first console.log and I can see my parent object with the child object on it, but for some odd reason, on the second console.log where I'm trying to log the child object, it will just return undefined. That seems weird to me considering the child object is there when I log the parent object.

Here is a JSFiddle you can run to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/4rcy66r7/

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you're using a synchronous request? And why not [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
    console.log(responseParent[i]);
    console.log(responseParent[i].child[i]);
                                       ^^^
```

You're using the same index for two completely independent arrays. All of those `child` arrays only have **ONE** object in them, always at index `0`, but you're trying indexes [1], [2], [3], etc... which simply do not exist.

It should be

```
    console.log(responseParent[i].child[0]);
                                        ^---
```

instead.

Comment: That works if I only have 1 child per parent, but what if I were to have multiple children? I would need to index on something? How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: then you need two loops.

Comment: I just figured that out while waiting for your reply. I needed a second loop indexing on the child objects. Thanks for steering me in the right direction!